# PHP and SQL Server - json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, json

When I execute this line **EXEC pl.spGetInfo 'JOHN DOE'** in SQL Server Management Studio, it works just fine.

When I call this php file, I am getting an error message '**Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string,..**' and I cant' find the problem.

```
<?php 

    // BD
    $conn = dbConnect();

    // Assign parameter values
    $name = 'JOHN DOE';

    $data = getRecords($conn, $name);

    function dbConnect(){
        $DBSERVER = "xxx1";
        $DBUSER   = "xxx2";
        $DBPASS   = "xxx3";
        $DBNAME   = "xxx4";

        // OBDC
        try 
            {       
            $pdo = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={SQL Server};Server={$DBSERVER};Database={$DBNAME}", $DBUSER, $DBPASS);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            //die(json_encode(array('outcome' => true)));
            //echo "Connected successfully";
            return $pdo;
            }
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
            {
            //die(json_decode(array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect')));
            echo "Connection failed: " . $ex->getMessage();
            }
    }

    function getRecords($cn, $myname){
        // Prepare the statement
        $sql = 'EXEC pl.spGetInfo ?';
        $stmt = $cn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $myname, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);         

        try{
            // Execute the statement 
            $stmt->execute(array($myname));

            // Records found
            $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            // Free the statement and connection resources
            $stmt->closeCursor();       

            // Return
            return $row;

        }catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Statement could not be executed.\n";      
            die(json_decode(array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect')));
            echo "Connection failed: " . $ex->getMessage();         

            // Free the statement and connection resources
            $stmt->closeCursor();
         } 
    }

?>
```

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: Do you mean to use `json_encode()` ?

Comment: The exception is caused by the multiple bindings, you're doing it both ways.

Comment: -1 for TL;DR, the error would clearly state Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, **array given** in /path/file.php on **line 123** - but you redacted that part.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone a typo closure right? change `de` to `en`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason its seems that your PHP code runs in the catch branch and hits `die(json_decode(array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect')));`

`json_decode` expects a string and returns an array (mostly) but you want to go the other way. So use `json_encode()`.

Comment: For debugging purposes only, might be good to include `$e->getMessage()` in the array, or comment the line out so the following line can echo the exception

Comment: When I inserted $e->getMessage(), I got a more specific message and add 'SET NOCOUNT ON;' to my stored procedure and it's working. Thanks you all.